# Knockout: how to validate object observale

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am binding to an observable object as follows:

```
<input data-bind="value: currentSelected().Title" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
```

I want the field on the object to be required and the save button below not to work unless the Title has been filled in:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-bind="click: saveBlogEntries">Save</button>
```

This is how I am setting currentSelected:

```
var newBlogEntry = new NewBlogEntry();
var newBlogEntryObservable = new NewBlogEntryObservable(newBlogEntry);
self.currentSelected(newBlogEntryObservable);
```

The definition for the function NewBlogEntry() is:

```
function NewBlogEntry()
{
    return { "Id": 0, "Title": "", "Description": "", "Tags": [] };
}
```

What is the best way to disable the save button, or when clicked show a validation message next to the Title field?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [knockout disable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html) binding on your button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-bind="disable: currentSelected().Title() == '', click: saveBlogEntries">Save</button>
```

To simplify the data-bind, you could have a computed observable for the empty title condition:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-bind="disable: currentSelected().HasNoTitle(), click: saveBlogEntries">Save</button>

HasNoTitle = ko.computed(function () { this.Title() == '' });
```

To get this binding to work, you would need the Title property to be observable.

```
Title = ko.observable('');
```